# Create JSON request body for POST API2 with one dynamic field which comes from API1 response

Tags: karate

I have started using Karate from 1 month.

Scenario
API1 gives output with below values
Authid
Callbackvalue
Getcaptchavalue

- authid = response.authid

Now I need to use this authid in next API POST request JSON

Example request

```
Data { authid : hdjsjenegekkwh,
Callbackvalue : anyvalue
Getcaptchatoken : hardcoded token}}
```

How to update response field authid from api1 to JSON request api2 (which I am storing in a JSON file and reading in scenario 2 for api2)

Rest all values can remain same.

Need to just update 2 fields in JSON request authid and getcaptchatoken.

Comment: Issue resolved after writing below code * replace authenticateRecaptchaPayload
      | token               | value  |
      | ${authId}           | authId |
      | ${googleTokenID}    | googleTokenID|

    * json authenticateRecaptchaRequest = authenticateRecaptchaPayload